# Show loading gif for one button only

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, loading, animated-gif

i don't have expirience with js, so i need help.

i found some js scripts, how to show loading gif for all submit buttons and i'm trying to show that gif for one submit button only.

How it looks like:

```
  function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    var modal = $('<div />');
    modal.addClass("modal");
    $('body').append(modal);
    var loading = $(".loading");
    loading.show();
    var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
    var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
    loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}

$('form').live("submit", function () {

    ShowProgress();

});
```

CSS:

```
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: White;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

it's one to one expample from: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx

And i need to use it for this button only:

asp:Button ID="InitDataButton" OnClick="InitData_Click" runat="server" Text="Show" Width="110px" Height="30px"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I don't know your server side but I checked the reference you provided. So here is another solution. Try move the script from the IsPostBack in Page_Load() to the button click handler for this button. I assume you are using VB, but the idea is the same for C#.

```
Dim script As String = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=InitDataButton]').click(); });"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, "load", script, True)
```

Comment: Hello Isabel, it doesn't work for my page at all. May be i should set some other parameters for the button. I tried to call js function from c# method, but the pic appears on the page after processing...

Comment: hm.. doesn't work. I put ClientIDMode="Static" into the button parameters.

Comment: document.getElementById('<%=InitDataButton.ClientID%>') doesn't work too

Comment: it looks like the script cannot get button id. i'm using c#.

Comment: string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=InitDataButton]').click(); });";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", script, true);

Comment: It's done like this:$(document).ready(function ({$("#InitDataButton").click(function () {ShowProgress();});}); and at first i used e.priventDefault(); but it doesn't close the pic after c# method. @Thanks for support, Isabela!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#InitDataButton" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  ShowProgress();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

And [**LIVE EVENT**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed from version 1.9 onwards, so better avoid using it.

Comment: Hello Sanki, it also doesn't work on my page. i changed the link to src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js". The pic doesn't appear...